# Statelessness implies referential transparency?

Tags: haskell, stateless, referential-transparency

I have this code

```
data Slist a = Empty | Scons (Sexp a) (Slist a) 
data Sexp a = AnAtom a | AnSlist (Slist a)
data Fruit = Peach | Apple | Pear | Lemon | Fig deriving (Show,Eq)

sxOccurs oatm sxp =
  let slOC Empty = 0
      slOC (Scons se sls) = (seOC se) + (slOC sls)
      seOC (AnAtom atm) = if (atm == oatm) then 1 else 0
      seOC (AnSlist sla) = slOC sla
  in seOC sxp
```

As you can see in `sxOccurs` I've got two helper functions inside the `let` which are "mutually self-referential" as my *The Little MLer* calls them: `slOC` and `seOC`. So in SML you must use the keyword `and` to let them know about each other and "cross-reference" each other. BTW, `sxOccurs` counts the number of a specific `AnAtom` objects in an s-list, in my example atoms are `Fruit` variables.

My question is, is this an example of referential transparency? Similarly, in Davie he gives this example

```
let s0 = emptyStack
    s1 = push 12.2 s0
    s2 = push 7.1 s1
    s3 = push 6.7 s2
    s4 = divStack s3
    s5 = push 4.3 s4
    s6 = subtStack s5
    s7 = multStack s6
    s8 = push 2.2 s7
    s9 = addStack s8
in popStack s9
```

noting that a stack in Imperative-land is constantly mutating the stack, while Haskell is creating a new `si` variable for each stack operation. Then he says that each of these lines could be shuffled into a different order and the outcome would be unchanged. AFAICT this is the same basic idea as my `sxOccurs` when it doesn't care what order I present the sub-functions. So, again, is this the deeper meaning of referential transparency? If not, what is this I'm showing here?

Comment: "Referential transparency" means "same input yields same output".

Comment: Then what have I described above?

Comment: The first example is "mutual recursion", and the second I'm not sure there is a special term for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Referential transparency means this, and only this: you may replace a variable by its definition without changing the meaning of the program. This is called "referential transparency" because you can "look through" a reference to its definition.

For example, you write:

```
slOC Empty = 0
slOC (Scons se sls) = (seOC se) + (slOC sls)
seOC (AnAtom atm) = if (atm == oatm) then 1 else 0
seOC (AnSlist sla) = slOC sla
```

Here's a couple transformations you could make, thanks to referential transparency:

```
-- replace slOC by its definition
seOC (AnSlist sla) = (\v -> case v of Empty -> 0; SCons se sls -> seOC se + slOC sls) sla
-- replace slOC by its definition *again*, starting from the previous line
seOC (AnSlist sla) = (\v -> case v of
    Empty -> 0
    SCons se sls -> seOC se + (\v -> case v of
        Empty -> 0
        SCons se sls -> seOC se + slOC sls
        ) sls
    ) sla
-- replace slOC by its definition in another equation
slOC (Scons se sls) = seOC se + (\v -> case v of Empty -> 0; SCons se sls -> seOC se + slOC sls) sls
-- or, you could replace seOC by its definition instead
slOC (SCons se sls) = (\v -> case v of
    AnAtom atm -> if atm == oatm then 1 else 0
    AnSlist sla -> sLOC sla
    ) se + slOC sls
-- or you could do both, of course
```

Well, of course, right? By now you may be thinking, "But Daniel, how could this property ever fail?". I will turn briefly to another language to illustrated: C.

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(*x));
x[0] = 42;
printf("%d\n", x[0]);
```

In case you don't read C well, this creates a new variable named `x`, allocates some space for it, writes 42 into that space, then prints out the value stored in that space. (We should probably expect it to print `42`!) But I've defined `x = malloc(sizeof(*x))` in the first line; can I replace `x` by this definition elsewhere?

No! This is a very different program:

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(*x));
malloc(sizeof(*x))[0] = 42;
printf("%d\n", x[0]);
```

It's still a syntactically valid program, but now `x[0]` has not been initialized at the moment we reach the line that prints it -- because we allocated a second, independent chunk of space, and initialized that other space instead.

This turns out to be the main way that other languages violate referential transparency: when you have variables whose value can change, it is not safe to replace references to them by their defined value, either because it may have changed since then or because this will cause it not to change in the way the rest of the program expected it to. Haskell eschews this ability; variables, once assigned a value, are never modified.

Answer (score 3):

What you've described, as indicated in the comments already, is more accurately referred to as "mutual recursion", when two functions call each other in the course of their evaluation. Referential transparency, in effect, says that, given the exact same inputs, a function will produce the same outputs. This is not true in, say, Python, where we could write this function

```
global_var = 0

def my_function():
    return global_var

my_function() # 0
global_var = 100
my_function() # 100
```

We called `my_function` with the same inputs, but it mysteriously produced a different output. Now, of course, in this example, it's obvious why that is, but the idea behind referential transparency is that, in real-world code, it's not going to be that obvious. If the language you're working in *doesn't* have referential transparency and indeed if the language encourages action-at-a-distance style mutation, then you'll inevitably end up with functions that access mutable state you don't know about. A well-written function will include extensive documentation about these corner cases, but if you've ever worked on any mid-size or larger code base, you know "well-documented function" is a rare sight.

In Haskell, there's no way* to write a function like the above Python function. At worst, we can wrap it in `IO`

```
myFunction :: IORef Int -> IO Int
myFunction = readIORef
```

But now the type signature alone tells us, at a glance, "something fishy is going on here; buyer beware", and even then we can only access the one global variable the `IORef` gives us access to.

*There's no way to write the function in Haskell short of exploiting `unsafePerformIO`, behind which there be many dragons. With `unsafePerformIO`, we can pretty obviously break referential transparency, which is why it's a function called "unsafe" in a module called "unsafe" that every Haskell tutorial ever tells you to forget about and never use.